# What are the issues of having multiple database collations in single SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, high-availability

I've recently inherited a SQL Server cluster which is a multi instance A/A setup.

Currently it has 6 instances, 3 are running large single databases with high transaction rates, which I'll leave alone, but the other 3 host multiple databases in each instance, and have been split down by collation.

The three collations are:

- Latin1_General_CI_AS,
- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, and
- SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2

Some databases are not being used, so can come off the cluster completely, some databases do not warrant being part of the cluster and will be moved to virtual boxes.

My question is what to do with the remaining databases. I would like to merge them into a single instance for ease of management. Few of the databases interact with each other, and those that do have the same collation.

What are the various cons of doing this, and importantly will it in any way affect updates and patching of the instances?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if the collations are explicitly used everywhere, then you won't necessarily have problems.  But, you very well could.

One big issue is constants in queries.  They inherit the default collation of the database where the query is run.  If you change the collation, then queries might fail or their performance might change.  Incompatible collations can affect the use of indexes.

I would be very careful about having multiple collations at all in the system.  I think you should test changing the databases to a common collation, and then work to unify them.  If a different collation is needed for a particular purpose, then isolate that code and uses *explicit* collations, rather than *default* collations for the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

When moving a database to an instance of a different collation, be mindful that the instance collation determines the collation of database names, variables, GOTO labels, and tempdb.  Going from a case-insensitive instance collation to a case-sensitive or binary collation will break code unless the definition and use of variables and GOTO labels exactly matches case.  Similarly, going from case-sensitive/binary to case-insensitive will cause problems if variables/labels differ only by case.

Also, column collation of temp tables will use the instance collation unless `COLLATE DATABASE DEFAULT` is explicitly specified.  This may result in collation conflict errors when using objects in tempdb.

Consequently, code remediation may be required to consolidate databases of different collations into a single instance.  Instance patching will not be affected.

Having worked in a mixed collation environment, I can say it is something to avoid but can be difficult to remediate for large legacy applications.